# How can I use that sliding tab widget on the Android 2.0+ lockscreen?

Tags: android, widget, tabs, sliding

I'm interested in using it for one of my apps and I was wondering how I can use one of them.
Are there any other similar widgets out there for 2.0+?

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do the trick:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html